# Return city in which most people live - stream()

Tags: java, java-stream, java-17

I have a class called Person (name,surname,city,age)  and I added to it persons.

I have  to find the  city that lives the most people - in my case is "Meerdonk". I tried using stream(), but I cannot figure out how.

This is my code:

```
 public static Optional<Person> getMostPopulateCity(List<Person> personList) {
     return personList.stream()
            .filter(person -> person.getCity()
            // here
            .max(Comparator.comparing(Person::getCity));
   }
```

At `// here`, I don't know what I should do to get my most populated city, and if  max. is OK to be used, as I want to get the max (most populated city).

Can someone explain me please what I should use to get out the most populated city? Or just to let me know what I have wrong?

Comment: You could map the stream of `Person` into a map of `City`, and find the most occurring element. Something like this would work: `personList.stream().map(person -> person.getCity())`. This returns a stream of cities, and you can simply find the most occuring element from this stream.

Comment: Btw, why is your method returning `Optional<Person>` when you are trying to get an instance of a city? Wouldn't it make more sense to return `Optional<City>`?

Comment: I'd suggest you use a grouping collector to collect the number of persons by city (e.g. using `collect(Collectors.groupingBy(person -> person.getCity(), Collectors.counting()))` )and then look for the city with the higest count value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Collectors.groupingBy` to group persons by city, then extract the map entry with the most people like so (assuming cities are strings):

```java
return personList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getCity)) // Map<String, List<Person>>
        .entrySet().stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getValue().size())) // Optional<Map.Entry<String, List<Person>>
        .map(Entry::getKey);
```

Comment: i di not thin about `groupingBy` - Thanks for it ,  that really help :)

Comment: It’s a waste of memory to collect the groups into `List`, just to call `size()` afterwards. When you use `Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getCity, Collectors.counting())` the groups get collected to counts in the first place, saving intermediate memory and simplifying the subsequent operation to `.max(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getValue()))`

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @Thomas above, use a grouping collector with counting collector to collect the number of persons by city and then look for the city with the higest count value:

```
         Optional<String> result = persons.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getCity, Collectors.counting())) // Map<String, Long>: Key -> city, Value -> count of persons with such city
                .entrySet().stream()
                .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()) // looking for highest count value
                .map(Map.Entry::getKey);
```